# How to view the current thread heap and variables?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread question.

consider the following simple method.

```
void do_something(){
//access the current thread heap memory content!?
}
```

And we would call it from different threads, the question is how would I access the called(current) thread heap memory?! just something like eclipse debug mode.

I know this is a weird question and there are much better solutions to accomplish this, but I just want to know.

I also could get the current stack by `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, but It's not really a real stack(at least for me) I just expected something like above, but I don't know how!

```
push str
call method0
pop str
push abc
push cvb
call method2
...
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe I misunderstood what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heap content is hard to get hold of since the heap implementation is JVM dependent. You can however get hold of such information via the [Java Virtual Machine Tools Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine_Tools_Interface). This is what Eclipse and other debuggers do. Remember that you have to run you application in debugging mode in order to make use of this interface. You can find documentation on Java debugging on the [pages of Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html).

What you describe to be a stack comes closest to [Java byte code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode). It is much easier to get hold of that. (Byte code represents a method implementation.) You can look at [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) which is a framework for reading Java classes. (Byte code operates on top of a stack but it is not one by itself.)

For your information: Java knows different kind of stack

- A thread's *method stack*: Each thread has a stack of methods that were called for this thread were the current method is on top of the stack. If the top method calls another method, this called method is pushed on top of this stack and becomes the new current method.
- Each such method has a *call stack* where values are pushed and poped from during method invocation. In order to add two numbers, for example, you need to push two numbers on this call stack and direct an addition by a specific byte code instruction.
- Besides these two most commonly referred *Java stacks*, a Java virtual machine has several internal stacks such as the *native method stack*. This is very implementation specific and you normally do not want to mess with this memory area.

If you just want to analyze the normal path a method goes without actually tracing a running method invocation, have a look at ASM. Otherwise, you chose a quite difficult task.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to run the application in debug mode, it just eats up the CPU and memory

Comment: Well, the reason for this is that the JVM needs to make certain information available for an external application. As long as you require this information, there is no other feasible way. As long as you do not want to scan the Java heap yourself and this is something you really do not want to do.